# Best portfolio/gallery/carousel slideshow plugin with thickbox?

Tags: plugins, gallery

I'm creating a web portfolio, and would like somethnig with carousel and thickbox/lightbox fuctionality?

Basically, I'd like something to show a certain part of the image in a slideshow carousel, and when you click on it, it'll show the full image in like a lightbox, with a description (the title?) below.

I've tried 10+ plugins now and had no joy, apart from a few paid ones which I'd rather avoid if possible

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Personally I don't like most of the gallery plugins out there, they're either too bloated or don't utilize the attachment/gallery functionality. I would use [Jcarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) and [jquery thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) together - this you'll have to have an understanding of implementing jquery and using [enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

After that there are two ways to do this. Have one page called portfolio or whatever you like and attach all images there. This is best if there isn't a lot of individual content for each image. Then in your template call all the attachments using an attachment query.

```
        <?php
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'title' => $attachment->post_title,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'description' => $attachment->post_content,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, $size = 'full', $attr = '', false);                   
        }                                   
    } ?>
```

Here you can call `wp_get_attachement_image` and it gets the whole src of the image or you can use `wp_get_attachment_url` to just get the image url and then add the rel='thickbox' to your image href.

The other way of doing this is creating a custom post type. Then each individual post would have an attached image, description, etc and you could write a query to call all the posts into the jcarousel and then use `the_post_thumbnail('your-custom-size)` to call each of the images posts in thumbnail size (thumbnail) and use the thickbox (full size) to make them larger.

I hope I haven't confused you, as you didn't state your level of knowledge of WordPress/coding.

For more on `the_post_thumbnail` you can go [here](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/).
And for more on `wp_get_attachment_url` you can read up [here](http://digwp.com/2009/08/awesome-image-attachment-recipes-for-wordpress/)